# How can I prevent Ruby's inverted character class from matching newline characters?

Tags: regex, ruby, regex-negation

TLDR: How can I make Ruby's regex engine exclude newlines from inverted character classes when multi-line matching is disabled?

### Background

With most regular expression engines I've used, it is not possible to match across lines unless the multi-line modifier is specified.  The `.` operator should match any character except a newline, and an inverted character class (`[^x]`) also should not match a newline.  For example, with ripgrep:

```sh
printf "a\nb\nc\nd" | rg '^a.*b.*c.*d$'
# [no output]

printf "a\nb\nc\nd" | rg '^a[^x]*b[^x]*c[^x]*d$'
# [no output]
```

The `^` and `$` operators should match the start and end of any line, not just the whole string, as shown here:

```sh
printf "a\nb\nc\nd" | rg '^c$'
# c
```

With the multiline option, ripgrep can match across lines:

```sh
printf "a\nb\nc\nd" | rg --multiline --multiline-dotall '^a.*b.*c.*d$'
# a
# b
# c
# d

printf "a\nb\nc\nd" | rg --multiline --multiline-dotall '^a[^x]*b[^x]*c[^x]*d$'
# a
# b
# c
# d
```

Ruby also does not allow `.` to match newlines unless the `m` modifier is present, and the `^` and `$` operators can match on any line within a string:

```rb
"a\nb\nc\nd".match(/^a.*b.*c.*d/)
# => nil

"a\nb\nc\nd".match(/^c$/)
# => #<MatchData "c">

"a\nb\nc\nd".match(/^a.*b.*c.*d/m)
# => #<MatchData "a\nb\nc\nd">
```

### The problem

However, Ruby's regex engine is matching newlines when given an inverted character class, *even without the multiline modifier*.  This is very unexpected!

```sh
# This should return nil!
"a\nb\nc\nd".match(/^a[^x]*b[^x]*c[^x]*d$/)
# => #<MatchData "a\nb\nc\nd">

"a\nb\nc\nd".match(/^a[^x]*b[^x]*c[^x]*d$/m)
# => #<MatchData "a\nb\nc\nd">
```

I've tried Ruby 1.9.3, 2.7.2, and 3.0, and they all exhibit this behavior.  So this has been present in Ruby for a very long time.

### The question

I frequently use regular expressions when writing specs for something that generates multi-line text.  Having to specify `\n` whenever I use an inverted character class is a pretty big hit to productivity and violates the principle of least astonishment.

So, how can I make Ruby's regex engine exclude newlines from inverted character classes when multi-line matching is disabled?

Comment: What is "ripgrep"? Note `"a\nb\nc\nd".match?(/^a[^x]*b[^x]*c[^x]*d$/) #=> true`.

Comment: are you willing to use `lines.select` type maps to force the linebreaks to an array when you don't want to use a multi-line search?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Ripgrep is a really fast alternative to grep, written in Rust.  I use it for quickly searching my code, and the amount of attention to detail given to its regex handling leads me to using it as a benchmark for other regex engines.

Comment: @Jad not an unreasonable workaround, but I'd still like to have a way to tell Ruby *not* to match `\n` ever, unless I've specified `/m` on the regex, no matter what.